# What can I do if I mess up a voicemail?

Tags: phone

Sometimes when I leave a voice mail I can mess it because I'm not expecting to have to leave a voicemail and are unsure what to say and end up stumbling and not effectively expressing myself.

What can I do in these situations?

Comment: I voted to close this because, despite this being *good to know*, it is more of a "how to..." **[using a product in the way it was designed to be used](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)** than a life hack workaround as defined by this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you push the # key while in the middle of recording a voicemail you will be able restart the current recording and start recording your message again.

You can keep resetting by pushing this button as much as you like, until you are satisfied with your message.

Comment: Is this an international standard and works on every voicemail?

Comment: I'm sorry to mention this, but I didn't know we can answer our own question? Same concern with Alex, does it work with all cellphone carriers?

Comment: Usually you press pound and you hear options, one of which is usually to erase and re-record. Option 3 is most common, I've found.